# navigation bar outside div

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain why the navigation bar is below the specified `<div id="navigation >` tag looking at the below code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Record Store</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation" >
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Vinyl Stock</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS

```
* {
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#container {
    margin: auto;
width: 800px;
border: 1px solid black;
min-height: 600px;
z-index: -9;
}

#title {

margin:auto;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#navigation{
border: 1px solid black;
height: auto;
background-color: yellow;
}


.navbar {
}

.navbar ul {
}
.navbar li {

    float: left;
    font: bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
    height: auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    display: inline;
}
.navbar a {
    border-right: 1px solid #1F5065;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help me tidy up the bar.  I'm a beginner in learning CSS and HTML.

Comment: Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Pb7Uy/ Now what change do you want

Comment: Why is the <ul> tag holding the navigation bar below the <div id="nvaigation"> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are floating your list elements without clearing them. Add this to your CSS

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

and then add the clearfix class to your ul.navbar

```
        <ul class="navbar clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vinyl Stock</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
        </ul>
```